# Unable to load data from server on webservice with php and android

Tags: php, android, web-services, api, httpresponse

Android cannot get data when I include function.php file.But Android get data when I remove file include code in current php file.How to solve this error.I wanna use some function in function.php file.So I must use include code to call function.php.

I've no idea.is it android or php fault?

My PHP version : 5.3.10
apache version : 2.2.21

My android code:

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 500000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 500000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(CategoryAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }

        // parse json data and store into arraylist variables
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

            JSONObject feed = object.getJSONObject("Feeds"); 

            FeedItem.allFeedItemsList.add(new FeedItem(Integer.parseInt(feed.getString("id")), feed.getString("name"), feed.getString("post_img"), feed.getString("post_description"), feed.getString("userimage"), feed.getString("post_date"), feed.getString("post_title")));   
        }
```

Anyone can help??????????

Comment: its not on android end..pls check your php code

Comment: @NightCrawler...ok, thanks. I had check so many time, but i get data without including function.php. but can't get data when using. So how to do, please....

Comment: sorry @thet i am not a php guy.. your android code seems fine to me and that's why i told you that its a php issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i can solve my error by Encoding in ANSI. Since I Encode in UTF-8, android can't load. Now, It is fine and ok. Thanks.......

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library:-https://github.com/Abhishekpalodath/FetchServerUtil-Android.git.
You can also load real-time data using this.